# Robot moves forward in rviz and backward in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I can't figure out why my robot moves forward in rviz and backward in gazebo when I publish to a positive value /cmd_vel linear.x, and moves backward in rviz and forward in gazebo when it's a negative linear.x value.

I think the ideal thing is to have the robot move in the same direction in both rviz and gazebo

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321217/robot-moves-forward-in-rviz-and-backward-in-gazebo/) by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Flipping the base_link by 180 degrees fix the error.

https://answers.ros.org/question/249457/how-to-turn-the-orientation-of-the-jackal-robot/

---

Originally posted by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) with karma: 91 on 2019-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [beluga](https://answers.ros.org/users/39391/beluga/) on 2022-03-17**:
So did you flip the base_link according to the base_footprint?

Do you think this may cause problems later when navigation stack etc are involved?